# PHP include path ignored

Tags: php, propel, include-path

At the moment i am facing a problem with the include path in php.

For Propel to function correctly I need to add the build/classes directory to my include path as explained here: http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#setting-up-propel

When i print the include path with **echo get_include_path();** Its printing the right directories. But when Propel try's to include a file there is a Fatal error: "Class not found".

The server is a local xampp webserver running on PHP 5.4.7 and Windows 8.

Does someone know's a solution?

With kind regards,

Jelmert

Comment: try including the file manually `include("/full/path/to/php.php") by it's full path to make sure that the user running the apache service is able to read the files.

Comment: In addition to @Orangepill's suggestion, is your classmap up to date? (You can update it with `C:/...> propel-gen.bat convert-conf`)

Comment: Thanks @jakerella, after updating my classmap it works correctly! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jakerella comment suggest i needed to update my classmap by running the command:

```
propel-gen convert-conf
```

Everything works fine at the moment :) Thanx Stackoverflow users!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that propel libraries comes with xampp, I found a link where it explains how to install propel in xampp on windows, hope it helps.

http://blog.spooxe.com/blog1.php/2010/11/07/a-solution-to-install-propel-in-a-xampp-environment